# sum (case when else end) statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a SQL Server SQL statement that works but it is seemingly messy and inefficient.  It checks each row of data for its data and groups it into `Yesterday`, `WeektoDate`, `MonthtoDate`, and `YeartoDate` and sums each field by the group. Is there a better way to do this?

Below is a sample of what I have, there are actually 15 or so fields in the actual query, which makes for a long `SELECT` query, Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT
    sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @YesterdayMorning and @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Calls ELSE 0 END) AS Calls_Yesterday
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @YesterdayMorning AND @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Time ELSE 0 END) AS Time_Yesterday
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @WTDMorning and @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Calls ELSE 0 END) AS Calls_WTD
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @WTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Time ELSE 0 END) AS Time_WTD
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @MTDMorning and @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Calls ELSE 0 END) AS Calls_MTD
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @MTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Time ELSE 0 END) AS Time_MTD
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @YTDMorning and @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Calls ELSE 0 END) AS Calls_YTD
   ,sum(CASE when row_date BETWEEN @YTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday THEN Total_Time ELSE 0 END) AS Time_YTD
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Better fit for codereview as opposed to stack overflow?

Comment: It is a well known tecnique to handle cross tabs. See this article:   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: `Select [current select here] FROM TableName where row_date < @EndOfYesterday` will allow you to remove that from each statement.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get rid of the `CASE`, break them into multiple `SELECT` queries with `WHERE` conditions and then union them:

```
SELECT
    'Yesterday' AS Range
    SUM(Total_Calls) AS Calls,
    SUM(Total_Time) AS Time
FROM TableName
WHERE row_date BETWEEN @YesterdayMorning AND @EndOfYesterday
UNION
SELECT
    'WTD' AS Range,
    SUM(Total_Calls) AS Calls,
    SUM(Total_Time) AS Time
FROM TableName
WHERE row_date BETWEEN @WTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday
UNION
SELECT
    'MTD' AS Range,
    SUM(Total_Calls) AS Calls,
    SUM(Total_Time) AS Time
FROM TableName
WHERE row_date BETWEEN @MTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday
UNION
SELECT
    'YTD' AS Range,
    SUM(Total_Calls) AS Calls,
    SUM(Total_Time) AS Time
FROM TableName
WHERE row_date BETWEEN @YTDMorning AND @EndOfYesterday
```

Comment: This will not result same as OP's Output

Comment: @NoDisplayName I think the resulting output would actually be much nicer - maintaining the result set didn't seem to be within the parameters of OP's question, but I maintained the objective.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your query is that inefficient, the query plan looks ok, but I agree the code is a bit messy. I would consider some thing like this to avoid the duplicated code:

- Add all morning dates to a table
- Join dates to the call table
- SUM calls and call time

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2) = FORMAT(DAY(GETDATE()), '00'), @month VARCHAR(2) = FORMAT(MONTH(GETDATE()), '00'), @year INT = YEAR(GETDATE());
DECLARE @weekday INT = DATEPART(dw, GETDATE());
DECLARE @morningTime TIME = '08:00';
DECLARE @EndOfYesterday DATETIME2 = DATEADD(dd, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), ' 18:00')));

DECLARE @timeTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(255), FromDate DATETIME2);

INSERT INTO @timeTable
SELECT 'Yesterday', DATEADD(dd, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONCAT(@year, @month, @day, ' ', @morningTime)))
UNION ALL SELECT 'WTDMorning', DATEADD(dd, -(@weekday-1), CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONCAT(@year, @month, @day, ' ', @morningTime)))
UNION ALL SELECT 'MTDMorning', CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONCAT(@year, @month, '01', ' ', @morningTime))
UNION ALL SELECT 'YTDMorning', CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONCAT(@year, '01', '01', ' ', @morningTime))

SELECT t.Name, Total_Calls = SUM(c.Total_Calls), Total_Time = SUM(c.Total_Time) 
FROM @timeTable t
LEFT JOIN TableName c ON c.row_date BETWEEN t.FromDate AND @EndOfYesterday
GROUP BY ID, t.Name
ORDER BY ID
```

[image]

On my test data your query actually have a 15% lower query cost that my query, but with an index on the "call table" my query is 20% cheaper then yours.

**Index:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxRowDate
ON [dbo].[TableName] ([row_date])
INCLUDE ([Total_Calls],[Total_Time])
```

I am aware that this do not match your output 100%, but I do believe that rows are easier to work with than 15+ columns. This could also be converted to one row if needed.

**One row support:**

If it is needed, you could convert the rows to one line with dynamic sql. But it gets a bit more complex:

```
DECLARE @onRowconverter VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @onRowconverter = @onRowconverter + CASE WHEN @onRowconverter > '' THEN ', ' ELSE 'SELECT ' END +  CONCAT('[Calls_' + t.Name + '] = ', SUM(c.Total_Calls),  ', [Time_' + t.Name + '] = ', SUM(c.Total_Time))
FROM @timeTable t
LEFT JOIN TableName c ON c.row_date BETWEEN t.FromDate AND @EndOfYesterday
GROUP BY ID, t.Name
ORDER BY ID

EXEC(@onRowconverter);
```